# Extracting performance statistics from FTP session transcript

Tags: parsing, datetime, sed, awk

I've borrowed and written the following code to output the disconnect time. All works well but I'm curious as to how I could tighten/ shorten the code. If anyone feels like having some fun then I'd love to see what can be done. Be a learning lesson for me.

Excerpt of input:

```
ftp> !:--- FTP commands below here ---
ftp> lcd C:\Utilities\Performance_Testing\
\Utilities\Performance_Testing\: File not found 
Verbose mode On .
ftp> verbose
binary
200 Switching to Binary mode.
ftp> put "test_file_5M.bin"
200 PORT command successful.
150 Ok to send data.
226 File receive OK.
ftp: 5242880 bytes sent in Seconds Kbytes/sec.
ftp> 44.81117.00disconnect
221 Goodbye.
ftp> bye
```

Code:

```
#Obtain UT external put value.
ut1intput=$(awk '
  NR==70 {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
      if($i=="ftp>") {
        sub(/disconnect/, "", $(i+1));
        print $(i+1)
      }
    }
  }' filename.txt)

utintputvalue=`echo $ut1intput | awk -F. '{print $2"."$3}'| sed  's/^..//'`
```

Output:

```
utintputvalue is 117.00
```

Comment: Is your first "output" actually the input in the context of this question? Could you explain what "44.81117.00" means, and why that translates to a desired output value of 1220.98?

Comment: Sorry, I C/P and pasted the incorrect output (not enough coffee). Should read 117.00. The "44.81117.00" is FTP output in seconds. I've been asked to output "after the 100th of a second".

Comment: To clarify again… 44.81117.00 means a bit over 44.81 seconds, and you care only about the fact that it was 117.00 × 10^-5 seconds more?

Comment: Should have made myself clearer. The 44.81 is the output in seconds. The 117.00 is the speed in kb. I'm grabbing the data "after the 100th of a second". for some reason the info I'm be provided has this in that odd format.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the "Output" section is stored in "filename.txt", and assuming you have GNU tools:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\.\d\d)\d+\.\d\d(?=disconnect)' filename.txt
```

That's a perl regex meaning: prececeded dot and two digits, find some digits, a dot and two digits, followed by "disconnect". grep's `-o` option means "output only the matched text".